# discord.py | My bot cannot send DM to other bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I'd like to DM to a bot.
This is my code.

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
        user = await client.fetch_user(<BotID>)
        print(user.name)
        try:
            await user.send('')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

client.run(<TOKEN>)
```

I got this error.
"400 Bad Request (error code: 50007): Cannot send messages to this user"

Can't bot DM to other bot?

Comment: There's no features about what you wanted. And there's might any conflicts on the future if  the developers of discord added that features.

Comment: I doubt that's possible, because at least for user accounts it should give you `Forbidden` if they have their privacy set to not let you do that.

Answer (score -1):

Bots cannot send messages to each other

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32475718)

Comment: I haven't been able to leave comments when I wrote this answer and the question had no comments at the time.

Comment: Well, now you have. Even so, it should never have been posted.

Comment: This answer could still be salvaged if you would add sources for this statement, so it does not come across as just an opinion, but as a well researched, documented fact.